# Evaluate $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^6}{e^{7x}-1}\ dx$

Tags: calculus

Find the closed form of  $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^6}{e^{7x}-1}\ dx$

Comment: What have you tred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets prove the General result

$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{a-1}}{e^{bx}-1}\ dx = \dfrac{(-1)^{a-1}}{b^a}\displaystyle\int_0^1 \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} y^k \ln^{a-1} y \ dy$

$$=\dfrac{(-1)^{a-1}}{b^a}\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int_0^1 y^k \ln^{a-1} y\ dy$$

$$= \dfrac{(-1)^{a-1}}{b^a}\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{a-1} (a-1)!}{(k+1)^a}$$

$$=\dfrac{(a-1)!}{b^a}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k^a}$$

$$=\boxed{\dfrac{\Gamma{(a)} \times \zeta {(a)}} {b^a}}$$

$\therefore$  $$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{x^6}{e^{7x} - 1}\ dx =\dfrac{\Gamma{(7)} \times \zeta {(7)}} {7^7}$$

Comment: This should be the desired form.

Answer (score 0):

Using the well known identity, $$\sum_{k\geq0}x^{k}=\frac{1}{1-x}
 $$ if $\left|x\right|<1
 $ we get $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{6}\left(e^{7x}-1\right)^{-1}dx=\sum_{k\geq1}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{6}e^{-7xk}dx=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{7^{7}k^{7}}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{7-1}e^{-t}dx=\frac{\Gamma\left(7\right)\zeta\left(7\right)}{7^{7}}.
 $$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^6}{e^{7x}-1}\ dx&=\frac{1}{7^7}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^6}
{e^{u}-1}\ du\\
&=\frac{1}{7^7}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^{7-1}}{e^{u}-1}\ du\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(7)}{7^7}\frac{1}{\Gamma(7)}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^{7-1}}{e^{u}-1}\ du\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(7)}{7^7}\zeta(7)\\
\end{align}

Note: [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Definition)